# function parseJson is not a member of string

Tags: scala, sendgrid

i'm working with scala 2.12, and when i tried this functional test:

```
  "FilterJsonProtocol" should {
    "deserialize filter to json" in {
      val filter: Filter = BCC(true, "you@example.com")
      filter.toJson shouldEqual "{\"settings\":{\"enable\":1,\"email\":\"you@example.com\"}}".parseJson
    }
  } 
i get the error Error:(14, 95) value parseJson is not a member of String
      filter.toJson shouldEqual "{\"settings\":{\"enable\":1,\"email\":\"you@example.com\"}}".parseJson
```

this function is not available in scala 2.12 ?? or it's an other issue?

Comment: which json library are you using?

Comment: actually i'm working with spray "io.spray" % "spray-json_2.10" % "1.3.3"

Comment: If you're working with Scala 2.12 you need a _2.12 instead of _2.10. Or just use %% instead of %

Answer (score 5):

`parseJson` is not a method generally available on `String`.

In order to use it like that, there must be an implicit conversion in scope that can transform `String` into something that has a `parseJson` method.

For instance, in case you're using `spray-json`, you'll need to import

```
import spray.json._
```

and then you'll be able to invoke `parseJson` on a `String`

Comment: i already import spray.json._  but i still have the same problem